# How do I cut out a piece of a big string with javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, split

In javascript, I have a large string like

```
str="a lot of lines\n"
str+="foo\n"
str+="the stuff I want\n"
str+="bar and a lot more stuff\n"
```

How do I put just the part:

```
the stuff I want
```

between "foo" and "bar" into a new string variable?

Comment: If you know that it is between foo and bar, you may want to search for "Regular Expressions".

Comment: I know this is a very basic question, but I didn't find the right words how to search for it. Why is this such a bad question? It is an important thing for a beginner in javascript!

Comment: I think it's because your question did not specify which format exactly you are searching for. There are many possible solutions in such a way, that every single one works with your example, but only some work in your real-world application. The question has to be specific in a way that it is clear what pattern you are searching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on where exactly 'the stuff you want' is in the string you can do a similar approach to this one:

```
var str="a lot of lines\n";
str+="foo\n";
str+="the stuff I want\n";
str+="bar and a lot more stuff\n";

var stuff = str.split('\n')[2]; // the stuff i want
```

EDIT: 
If you want the stuff between foo and bar, then you can do something like:

```
var stuff = str.match(/foo((.|\n)*)bar/)[1]; // contains newlines!
```

Comment: thank you `split` was the thing I need!

Answer (score 3):

```
 var str = "a lot of lines foo the stuff I want bar and a lot more stuff"
 str.substring(str.indexOf("foo")+3,str.indexOf("bar") )
```

Comment: The solution lacks checks, but I +1 it because someone has to say that there's no law forcing regex upon everyone and everything, yet.

Answer (score -1):

```
var str="a lot of lines\n";
str+="foo\n";
str+="the stuff I want\n";
str+="bar and a lot more stuff\n";

// ------------------------------

var myRegex = /foo(.*)bar/;

if (myRegex.test(str)) {
  alert(myRegex[0]);
}
```

With a regex, it should do the trick.

Comment: It doesn't. The `\n` character is not matched by `.`.